# Is there an alternative to LIKE to get strings that are within another string within a column, using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Im building an application with Laravel, I know that LIKE isnt a laravel thing but im not sure in general if there is a better way to do this. Im allowing a user to add in characters to an input field and after the second character a type ahead shows matching results that they can click on. Everything works its just jumpy and slow.

```
$destinations = DB::table('destinations')->select('id','destination')
->where('published',1)
->where('destinations', 'like','%' . $request->chars . '%')
->get();
```

One thing that also keeps happening is it seems like if you put in uni ( for united states ) then kept typing the word a newer ask, like "unite" would return before "unit" which makes it jumpy.

Is there an alternative to LIKE that might be quicker or am I not even looking at the right thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/scout). It is a first-party Laravel plugin that is written to solve this exact problem.

Essentially, you install it via composer:

```sh
$ composer require laravel/scout
```

Publish the configuration:

```sh
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider"
```

Then register your model as `Searchable`:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class Destination extends Model
{
    use Searchable;
}
```

This is ***a lot*** more performant than hammering your database with queries every time the user types a key.

Comment: Hi Vincent I just looked through this and your right it seems this is the way to go, in the laravel tutorial it says I need to set up a queue and Algolia but your example doesn't have that, just making sure I need to do that in order to use this?

Comment: You need to either use Algolia, or write your own custom driver.